# iOS - pop a view in the parent UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

Here is how my current iPhone app is made:

```
UINavigationControllerA [viewA1 viewA2 viewA3]
viewA3 leads to UITabBarControllerB [viewB1 viewB2]
viewB2 leads to UINavigationControllerC [viewC1 viewC2]
```

I use custom navigation bars and everything is working greate.

My only problem is that **in the views of UINavigationControllerC I placed a UIBarButton in my custom navigation bar that should link to viewA3**, but I fail.

I know I can't do this:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Because UINavigationControllerC != UINavigationControllerA.

1. Is there a way to get the parent UINavigationController?
2. Is there a trick I could use to save UINavigationControllerA inside of UINavigationControllerC?

Thx in advance

Comment: you could use presentmodalviewcontroller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access `self.tabBarController.navigationController` instead of `self.navigationController`?

This may not work however as Apple explicitly state that putting a `UITabBarController` inside a `UINavigationController` is not supported.

Another option would be to access the root navigation controller from your appdelegate using something like:

```
((MyAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).yourNavigationController
```

Comment: [self.navigationController.tabBarController.navigationController popToViewController:...] worked!